# How can I get the title of a reddit post downloaded via the API?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

This is the meme command that I use for my discord bot,
How can I get the title of the reddit post that was selected?

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
  meme_subreddits = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot',
    'https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/new.json?sort=hot',
    'https://www.reddit.com/r/meme/new.json?sort=hot',
    'https://www.reddit.com/r/me_irl/new.json?sort=hot']
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
    async with cs.get(random.choice(meme_subreddits)) as r:
      res = await r.json()
      embed = discord.Embed(title="Meme Title", color=0x202225)
      embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I would reccomend using PRAW as it is a really good reddit API wrapper with good documentation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already getting the image of that random reddit post, you just need to also grab the title of that post:

```py
...
random_post = res["data"]["children"][random.randint(0, 25)]
image_url = random_post["data"]["url"]
title = random_post["data"]["title"]
...
```